# transform query string with ngresource for ransack query

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am using ransack in my Rails backend to make research.
I use Angularjs for my app and I would like to call my Rails controller with ransack formated query params, something like :

```
/conversations?q[subject_cont]=toto&q[status_eq]=1
```

I can't find any solution to transform any object to this query :/
I have tried to play with http interceptors but did not get any luck.

I am using ngresource to call my API.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, you could have something like:

`var params = {
  'q[subject_cont]': $scope.subjectCont',
  'q[status_eq]': $scope. statusEq'
}`

`$scope.conversions = Conversation.query(params);`